# columns with default NULL values returns as (None,) on SELECT python pymysql

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

I'm using pymysql module to connect the database to the python project.But I'm getting an error when I run a `SELECT` query to get a value of a column
This is my code block for sql query.

```
sql_check_record = 'SELECT `suggestions` FROM `temp_suggestions` WHERE `word`= "%s"' %key
cursor.execute(sql_check_record) 
new_val = cursor.fetchone() 
print(new_val)
```

When the value of **key** exists in the **word** column, and **suggestion** column is empty it returns this `(None,)`.
But when the value of **key** is not exist in the **word** column it returns `None`

I want to check whether the **suggestion** is `NULL`. As when the value of **suggestion** is `NULL` it returns `(None,)` how can I check whether it's `NULL` or not(if anything exists in the column). Because I want to concatenate to the existing value if a value exists.

Comment: you can use `val = new_val[0] if new_val else None` then you can use val and manipulate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sql_check_record = 'SELECT `suggestions` FROM `temp_suggestions` WHERE `word`= "%s"' %key
cursor.execute(sql_check_record) 
new_val = cursor.fetchone() 
print(new_val)
```

You can use

```
(new_val,)=cursor.fetchone()
if(new_val is None)
```

to check. If it returns (None,) then it's true.